# composition of coreflection and a reflection

Tags: category-theory

What would be the difference between the composition of a coreflection after a reflection (idempotent adjunction?) and the composition of a reflection after a coreflection?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I am not a category theory specialist but as I read papers on this, it would seem that to relate categories A and B, some create a category C which is a full subcategory of A and B or a create a category D where A is a full subcategory of D and B is a full subcategory of D. I am not sure of the difference between A as it relates to B in these two modes.

Comment: Note that also the full embedding functors may play a role. Exactly which functors do you want to compose? As stated, a coreflection $B\to C$ after a reflection $A\to B$ would assume $C$ is a coreflective full subcategory of $B$ which is a reflective full subcategory of $A$. I like to draw reflective subcategories as a potato pushed to the right side within a bigger potato.

Comment: I am looking more on the Scenario 1, using your example with B as a reflective subcategory of A but with B as a coreflective subcategory of C. A Scenario 2 would be that A is a coreflective subcategory of B and C a reflective subcategory of B. Composition would be A to C in both scenarios.